# How do I cancel a specific task in a collection of type Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

So I am trying to figure out a way to cancel specific tasks.
In the example I want to cancel 2 out of the 3 tasks that it spawns

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Counter();
    }));



    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

public static void Counter()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and if I were to do `while (someProperty)` and change `someProperty` to `false` then all the threads would get stopped. I want to stop 2/3, how do I do that?

Comment: Can't really cancel a task. You could abort a thread, I suppose, but that is usually a pretty bad idea. You need to write logic within the `Counter()` method that causes the loop to exit when a condition is met. You then "end" the task by setting that condition, causing it to exit the loop. For example, instead of `while (true)`, you could use `while (flag == true)` and set `flag` from your main code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to pass in a `CancellationToken` for each task you start if you want to cancel them individually:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var cancellationSources = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
      .Select(_ => new CancellationTokenSource())
      .ToList();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => Task.Run(
        () => Counter(cancellationSources[x].Token),
        cancellationSources[x].Token
    ));

    cancellationSources[1].Cancel();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

public static void Counter(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // or while(true) and token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); to throw instead

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```